# Conditional line-clamp in css

Tags: css, sass, ellipsis

I have a narrow span that I wanna use line-clamp to ellipsis after the second row. My issue is that if the first word is wider than the container it will have an ellipsis and the second word on a separate row will look as usual.
For ex:

[image]

I was wondering if I can set the line-clamp conditionally so if the first row exceeding the container width the second row won't be shown.

Comment: when you say ` conditionally `,  99% of the time it can't be done with CSS alone.

Comment: I understand, But maybe there's a way to hide the second row if ellipsis occurs in the first row. A CSS solution will be the best but js workaround will also be helpful